# Prove that: $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^T) = \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Prove that: $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^T) = \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})$.

(By $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{X})$ i mean the column space of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$.)

The inclusion in the direction $\supseteq$ was easy to prove. However, i can't prove the $\subseteq$ inclusion. Do you have a trick to prove this?

Maybe we also need a further restrition, like $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m\geq n$?

Comment: Suppose $y=A^TAx$. Can you write $y=A^Tz$?

Comment: I'm sorry, i got the direction of the inclusion wrong. I updated the question.

Comment: No worries ndrizza, that is an easy mistake to make!

Comment: Since you've proved the one of the inclusions, it's enough to prove that $\dim\left(\mathcal R\left(A^T\right)\right)=\dim\left(\mathcal R\left(A^TA\right)\right)$. I'd prove this by using the fact that $\dim\left(\mathcal R\left(A^TA\right)\right)=\dim\left(\mathcal R\left(AA^T\right)\right)$ and proving the (easier) equality $\mathcal R\left(A^T\right)=\mathcal R\left(AA^T\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at this is to use the fundamental fact that if $M$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix then the range of $M^T$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $M$.  (Gilbert Strang emphasizes this "four subspace theorem".)

Suppose $y \in R(A^T)$.  Then by the four subspace theorem, $y \in N(A)^\perp$.  But, it's easy to show that $A$ and $A^T A$ have the same null space.  So, we see that $y \in N(A^T A)^\perp$.  Now we invoke the four subspace theorem once more to conclude that $y \in R(A^T A)$.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed i proved $\mathcal{N}(A^TA)=\mathcal{N}(A)$. And repeating the theorem about the 4 fundamental subspaces was useful too!

Answer (score 0):

Every vector in the left hand side is of the form 
$$
A^t A u
$$
where $u$ is a vector in $R^n$. Rewrite that as

$$
A^t A u = A^t v
$$
where $v = A^t u$ is therefore a vector in $R^m$. Well, that vector is evidently in the range of $A^t$. Hence every vector in the left side is also in the right side.

Comment: I'm sorry, i got the direction of the inclusion wrong.

Comment: Best of luck; someone who doesn't mind having precious time wasted will  have to answer this one for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, for this, i can update the question to prove the set equality. Then we'll have it documented.